# How to improve overall performance of an android application?

Tags: android, performance, optimization, android-proguard

As I'm trying to reduce my android app and optimize it, I search for every possibilities to do that. Here what I found:

A. [Android Developer Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html)

> - Avoid Creating Unnecessary Objects
> - Prefer Static Over Virtual
> - Use Static Final For Constants
> - Avoid Internal Getters/Setters Use
> - Enhanced For Loop Syntax, etc.

B. https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/5-ways-to-optimize-your-code-for-android-5.0-lollipop

> - Use local variables instead of public class fields when possible.
> - Use the final keyword to hint that a value is constant
> - Use the final keyword for class and method definitions, etc.

C. Instead using `view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener...)`, use 
`view.setOnClickListener(this)`, by attaching listener to activity or fragment.

D. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidApplicationOptimization/article.html

E. http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/01/31/tips-for-reducing-apk-file-size/

> - Remove debug information.

F. http://hsc.com/Blog/Best-Practices-For-Memory-Optimization-on-Android-1

> - Use Optimized Datacontainers
> - Use Proguard And Zipalign

G. http://ernelljava.blogspot.se/2012/04/do-not-create-objects.html

> - Do not overuse String, use StringBuilder for working with String.

H. https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices

Are there any other tips that can help me optimizing my application?

Answer (score 1):

Check below points for better coding and optimization,

(-) Keep your coding clean and in small part,

(-) Don't write long one single function, separate it in small functions,

(-) Never call any network functionality on main thread, use always async task for that.

(-) On use done for any resource, quickly release it don't keep it in use to avoid deadlock situation.